# get the selected value,id from autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I would like to get the selected value,id from autocomplete

here is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/js/jquery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete(
    {
         source:'source.php',
    })
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="search" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

query is

```
$req = "SELECT id,name "."FROM mytable "."WHERE name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%' ";
```

Comment: Do you want to change the behaviour on different actions like `focus` or `select`, or do you want to change the way the item is rendered?

Comment: @super-qua thanks for the reply..I just want to get the id when i select an item.how can i get id by using select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is looking for items with a `label` and `value` set. 
For your case you have to adapt that, so autocomplete is using your `id` and `name` fields.

You can override the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) and access the fields with `ui.item.id` and `ui.item.name`. This would look something like this:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete(
{
     source:'source.php',
     select: function(event, ui) {
        // handle the user selecting the entry
        // access fields with ui.item.name and ui.item.id
     }

})
```

However, this might lead to your data not being displayed correctly, because autocomplete uses `label` and `value` fields by default.

To override the displaying behaviour, implement the [_renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) method to display your data.
An example how to do this can be found on the [examples page](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) in the source.